# WPF - Drag & Drop on Listbox ITEM

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I want to drop something not on the whole ListBox, but on a specific ListBoxItem. I'm handling the ListBox' Drop event - how can I find out, on which item the mouse is pointing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this now by setting `AllowDrop` and the `Drop` event handler not on the ListBox but to the control in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @lll Won't work if you need to support (multiple) null items, just had that problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest.aspx) to figure out which ListViewItem is at the given point. That said, there may well be an easier way to do what you require, but there's not really enough info to go on.

Comment: I tried this code:
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Songs))) {
                var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this.Playlists, Mouse.GetPosition(this.Playlists)); (in the Drop-handler) but it always returns null!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Songs))) 
 { 
   var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(myCanvas, Mouse.GetPosition(this.Playlists));
 }
```

If using a canvas, try performing your hittest relative to the Canvas (replace "myCanvas" with the reference)

Comment: is the playlist contained in a Canvas?